# PySide: round corner with stylesheet does not work

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, stylesheet, pyside

I want to make the corners of a widget around. In **PyQt** I have solved the problem with stylesheet, which worked well. I wanted to do the same in **PySide**, but for some reason it does not work.

here is my code:

```
TitelWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
TitelSizer = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
TitelWidget.setLayout(TitelSizer)
TitelWidget.setStyleSheet("QWidget#TitelWidget {border: 1px solid rgb(160,160,160); border-radius: 9px; background: QLinearGradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #f6f6f6, stop: 0.5 #ededed, stop: 0.55 #e4e4e4, stop: 0.6 #dbdbdb, stop: 1.0 #d2d2d2);}")
```

**my question is, what can be wrong in this case?**

Thanx

Answer (score 6):

The rounded corners won't apply if the radius * 2 is larger than either the height or width.  Try making the radius smaller or make sure that the size of your TitelWidget is at least 18px in both directions